# Obscure properties of binary operations

Tags: reference-request, binary-operations

The commutative, associative, and distributive properties of binary operations are very well-known. I am interested in more obscure properties of binary operations, which have nonetheless been studied in the mathematical literature. By property of binary operations, I mean either a unary property of a single binary operation, or a property of an ordered pair of binary operations. For example, the "switchable" property which I came up with is this: Given two binary operations $+$ and $*$ on a set $S$, the ordered pair $(+,*)$ is said to satisfy switchability if, for all $x,y,z$ in $S$, $(x+y)*z=x+(y*z)$. I am interested in such obscure properties, especially those which have been studied in some math paper or text.

Comment: You seem to be more interested in relationship between two binary operations, than studying single one.  If you are talking about a single binary operation, a group being solvable may is essentially a question about the binary operation. For two binary operations, being an integral domain, or  being a field, or being an algebraically closed field etc may be thought of as "obscure"  properties on the binary operations.  To put it in a nutshell,  a property on the group/ring/field is essentially property of the binary operation(s); obscure or not is a viewpoint.

Comment: Some of the many (essentially all elementary, however) references in my 2005 manuscript [Exotic Group Examples](https://web.archive.org/web/20170517021311/http://mathforum.org/kb/servlet/JiveServlet/download/206-2143964-7218194-629524/group-examples.pdf) might be of interest. Incidentally, I have made a few additions to this over the years, but I haven't really put a huge amount of time into it since 2005. Nonetheless, if you want the current version, then send me an email (see [my profile](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/13130/dave-l-renfro?tab=profile) for my email address).